# Sacar valores de una columna en mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Hola buena tengo el siguiente trozo de codigo en el cual lo que quiero conseguir es sacar los distintos estados que puede tener un pedido por ejemplo

```
#Estados de un pedido
#Entregado
#Pendiente
#Rechazado
```

Lo he intentado con este codigo pero me salen todos los pedidos y no consigo hacer para que me salgan solo 3

```
SELECT Estado FROM Pedidos;
```

Si alguien lo sabe se lo agradeceria un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si solo quieres obtener los valores distintos de una columna, la forma más sencilla es:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT Estado FROM Pedidos
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Deberías hacer una consulta como la siguiente:

```
SELECT Estado FROM Pedidos WHERE condicion.
```

Si bien he entendido tu pregunta, solo debes devolver tres dependiendo del estado, ¿no?

Respuesta abajo en comentarios

Comment: Gracias ya consegui resolverlo yo queria algo asi:

Comment: Si hago una consulta en la que muestro la columna estado la salida es "ENTREGADO, RECHAZADO, RECHAZADO, PENDIENTE, ENTREGADO" etc.....

Comment: Yo lo que queria era que la salida fuese solo los 3 posibles estados que puede cojer un pedido osea que la salida sea algo asi: "ENTREGADO, PENDIENTE, RECHAZADO"

Comment: Al final lo he conseguido con la siguiente linea: SELECT Estado FROM Pedidos
GROUP BY Estado;